# Trace of a function $v \in H_0^1$ along an edge shared by two elements

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-element-method

First, let me set the stage: suppose we have a bilinear form $B(u,v)=\int_\Omega \nabla u \cdot \nabla v \, \mathrm{d}x$, where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ and $u,v \in H_0^1(\Omega)$. Moreover, $\mathcal{T}$ is a triangulation of the space $\Omega$.Elementwise integration by parts leads to
$$ B(u,v)=\sum_{K \in \Omega} \left\{- \int_K \Delta u v \, \mathrm{d}x+\int_{\partial K} \nabla u \cdot \mathrm{n}_K v \, \mathrm{d}s\right\},$$
where $\mathrm{n}_K$ is the unit exterior normal vector to $\partial K$. I'm fine with all of that.

For the a posteriori analysis, the integrals over the boundary terms are rearranged. In the book it's written, that if an edge $e$ is shared by two elements $K_1$ and $K_2$, then $v|_{K_1}=v|_{K_2}$. I don't see why that should be true, as the function $v$ has not to be continuous.

Comment: Why do you need integration by individual elements instead of integration by $\Omega$? Your calculations may be useful when $v$ belongs to a discrete space. In that case, $v$ is supposed to be in $C(\Omega)$.

Comment: @jokersobak $v$ does belong to $H_0^1(\Omega)$, thus not a discrete space. The integration by individual elements is due to the fact that we want to estimate the error elementwise.

Answer (score 0):

As says @jokersobak , $v|_{K_1}=v|_{K_2}$ because $v\in H^1_0(\Omega)$ and then is continuous in $\Omega$  (to be more precise, $v$ has a continuous representant...  but since is inside an integral, it the same to say that $v$ is constant).